# Speeding up computation of 10^47 products with GPU or FPGA

Tags: performance, gpu, fpga

I need to compute scalar products of the form

```
T'*log(T)
```

where `T` is a very large Kronecker product of the form

```
T = 1;
for k=1:100
    T = kron(T, p(:,k));
end
```

where `p` is a `5 x 100` matrix of integers.

Since in the end the result is a scalar, I don't need to generate the Kronecker product array, and can simply sum online. However, each `p(:,k)` usually has ca. 3 unique values: This gives a total of approx `3^100` which is `10^47`, an immense number of combinations.

Do you think that there is any chance that I can use GPUs or FPGAs to get this computed in weeks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `1e47` is *too big* for that. Imagine, that you have a *supercomputer* with `1e6` nodes each of them has super GPU with `1e4` cores, and each core can perform `1e10` operations per second. So far so good it'll take

```
 1e47 / (1e6 * 1e4 * 1e10) = 1e27 seconds
```

`1e9` (*billion*) seconds is roughly `30` *years*. So we have to wait `3e19` years which by far exceeds the *age of the Universe* (`1.3e10`).